# Carbon is returning a wrong date? Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

I'm facing a really weird issue with Carbon in laravel... i'm trying to get a specific date like this:

```
    $now = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Costa_Rica');

    $currentYear = $now->copy()->year;

    $febmon = $now->copy()->month(2)->startOfMonth();
    dd($febmon);
```

It's supposed to return: `2018-02-01 00:00:00.0 America/Costa_Rica (-06:00)`

But instead i'm getting this: `2018-03-01 00:00:00.0 America/Costa_Rica (-06:00)`

I have already tried with all other month numbers, and works perfect but February... no idea what is wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the issue, my mistake but if anyone is facing this simple but odd issue:

I'm basing the date depending on `now()` and i'm setting the `month(2)` before i set the `startOfMonth()`

And because today is 30 then it's passing to the next month in February, which is March since February doesn't have 30 days, all i had to do is set `startOfMonth()` first... so it will take the right date.

Here is the right way:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Costa_Rica');

$febmon = $now->copy()->startOfMonth()->month(2); //Specify the month at last, and set the startOfMonth() first.
dd($febmon);
```